Rendering Issue: Series line/marker getting cut off by yAxis line chart highcharts
When the maximum value is 100 the line of the part of the graph is of a smaller thickness.
[![Line chart issue][1]][1]
The value cannot be more than 100.
yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tickAmount: 5,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}%',
            style: {
                color: 'var(--el-text-color-primary)'
            }
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/MBfNiRpB.png


It's difficult to tell from the low resolution screenshot what you're seeing and it could be due to anti-aliasing when creating/capturing the image. Could you add a higher resolution version. Do you see the same behaviour if the line is horizontal at another value (both on and off a divison)?

This is because the part of the line is outside the plot area.
As a solution, you can disable clip option for the series:
series: [{
  ...,
  clip: false
}]

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k3ed86c1/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.clip

Or make some space for the line by increasing y-axis scale:
yAxis: {
  ...,
  tickPositions: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
  endOnTick: false,
  min: 0,
  max: 101
}

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nrjfkdw8/
API Reference:
Similar thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3160
